Get row index of a pandas row knowing the row number
I have a Pandas dataframe that is the result of filtering over another dataframe, so the index of rows are not sequential since only some of the rows of the base dataframe are kept in the resulting dataframe.
I want to know the index of a given row position of the resulting dataframe. Let's say we want the index value of row 1, I know I can get row 1 using row = resulting_dataframe.iloc[0], but I don't know how to get the index for that row.
I tried resulting_dataframe.index[resulting_dataframe.iloc[0]], but I get an error, and I also tried resulting_dataframe.iloc[0].index, but I only get the row without index.
How can I get the index of the row?

If you want to get the index value by position, just slice/index:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,2]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.index[0] # 'a'

For the other way around, if your index value is unique, use get_loc:
df.index.get_loc('b') # 1

